# FIAM: firebase doesn't show message when triggering event

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I try to trigger event (firebase in-app message) programmatically, but firebase doesn't show any messages.

In log I see it:

```
2019-07-30 16:47:07.514 1890-1918/ru.ed.com.test.debug W/FIAM.Headless: Recoverable exception while reading cache: /data/user/0/ru.ed.com.test.debug/files/fiam_eligible_campaigns_cache_file (No such file or directory)
2019-07-30 16:47:07.515 1890-1918/ru.ed.com.test.debug W/FIAM.Headless: Recoverable exception while reading cache: /data/user/0/ru.ed.com.test.debug/files/fiam_impressions_store_file (No such file or directory)
2019-07-30 16:47:07.523 1890-1918/ru.ed.com.test.debug I/FIAM.Headless: Fetching campaigns from service.
2019-07-30 16:47:07.528 1890-1918/ru.ed.com.test.debug W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
2019-07-30 16:47:07.540 1890-1918/ru.ed.com.test.debug I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
2019-07-30 16:47:07.541 1890-1918/ru.ed.com.test.debug W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
2019-07-30 16:47:07.542 1890-1918/ru.ed.com.test.debug W/FIAM.Headless: Service fetch error: value
```

I triggered it like so:

```
FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().triggerEvent("Draft campaign")
```

Can someone help me? What's problem?

Comment: Not sure if I'm too late for this, but you could check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58995178/969016

Answer (score -1):

triggerEvent() is for Analytics events, not campaign names

Comment: This is not for Analytics! I figured it out and wrote an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58995178/969016