# InApp Messaging won't show message on custom event

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

using

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.2'
```

I get the message when using the "Test on device" feature in Firebase
I also get message when using the event "on_foreground" but I want to show a message not directly on app start, but when entering a new screen (when I send the event "Show_Category_Screen")

like this

```
FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(activity);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("Show_Category_Screen", null);
```

And I set the InApp Message trigger event to "Show_Category_Screen". But nothing happens

The event successfully shows up in the DebugView in Firebase

I see this in the log

```
I/FIAM.Headless: Successfully fetched 2 messages from backend
I/FIAM.Headless: Removing display event listener
I/FIAM.Headless: Already impressed InAppCategoryMessage ? : false
```

I have the same problem in my iOS app. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 7):

I started playing with in app messaging today and this took some figuring out using the famous trial and error technique.

There are two ways for triggering events:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent("main_screen_opened", null);
```

and

```
FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().triggerEvent("main_screen_opened");
```

I've published a campaign with the trigger `main_screen_opened`, as you cannot do this while testing, test messages are show on app open:

[image: Test on device screenshot]

Now, make sure you call `triggerEvent()` or `logEvent()` in the `onResume()` of the activity, **it won't work if you do it on the `OnCreate()`!**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent("main_screen_opened", null);
    FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().triggerEvent("main_screen_opened");
    ...
}
```

**NOTE:*** it will (probably?) not trigger the first time, to not bug the user right away. When you go to the home screen and go back into the app, it should show up now.

Edit: After some testing a bit more, it is ok if you put it in the `onCreate()`. When you check your logging, you'll see

```
Already impressed <your campaign name> ? : false
```

The second time you execute the `logEvent()` / `Trigger()`, the popup will show up

Comment: doesn't work for me either, I tried everything, but the message is still showing on splash screen even when the only event is "main_activity" which I log and trigger only in onresume of mainactivity

Comment: @ElJazouli that is weird. Are you sure you are not sending a test message and using a real published message?

Comment: what do you mean? I'm using "test on device", is that different than a real published message?

Comment: @ElJazouli please check my post and the image I added: when using `test on device`, the message is only triggered on app-open. It does not work on triggers and will therefore only show on the splashactivity

Comment: Thank you so much that explains everything, I just got an answer from a firebase team member about the issue and he said the same thing.

Comment: For anyone still having issues in 2023, the only way for this custom events to work is to use FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().triggerEvent() method, NOT FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent() because for some reason, InAppMessaging Firebase backend isn't recognizing that custom event.

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in app `build.gradle` file :

```
// in app messaging
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2
```

Add below lines in your starting activity in `onCreate()`

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);
FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().setAutomaticDataCollectionEnabled(true);
```

I resolved same issue using above steps.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.